# Guessing the programming language used for a software

Tags: windows

The question is simple from a programmer's point of view. How do you know which language / libraries has been used to develop a specific software product.

Say you have average knowledge of computing who can understand by checking product file (.exe, .dll, etc) names / versions that this piece of software has been written using Visual C++ / .Net / QT , etc.

Any solid ideas by which one can know about a programs's programming language?

Comment: This post may be helpful: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371460/find-programming-language-used

Comment: Assuming executable binaries or even some scripted type execuables (e.g., Java), check the library dependencies. If you need "libLangXYZruntime" its a good indication that language XYZ is involved.

Answer (score 0):

@baza92
Thanks for the link. It just opened my mind.

I do use ProcessExplorer, ProcessMonitor. 
For better investigation even one can use Spy++ utility provided with Visual studio. PEiD can be useful, but these days application program comes with packed method so PEiD is unabled to digg through those files.

So I would strongly suggest anyone who is or will be looking for these things follow the below steps.

- Investigate program files - .exe, .dll, .ocx
- Check loaded modules into program memory by ProcessExplorer or similar
- Use Spy++ to get the window class, try to search that on google